# output content in second occurrence

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, scripting

I have a log file that is producing output as:

```
[+] [1.1.1.1] LOG HERE
```

I would like to know how I can extract the IP from the log to send to a "clean" file, that only list the IP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `awk`, tested on `GNU Awk 4.1.3`, not sure if it won't work with other versions

```
$ cat ip.txt 
[+] [1.1.1.1] LOG HERE

$ awk -F'[][]' '{print $4}' ip.txt 
1.1.1.1
```

- `-F'[][]'` set input field separator as `[` or `]`
- `{print $4}` print the 4th field

With `sed`, assuming input file has consistent pattern like shown in sample

```
$ sed 's/.*\[//; s/].*//' ip.txt 
1.1.1.1
```

- `s/.*\[//` delete from start of line up to last `[` in the line
- `s/].*//` from the so modified line, delete everything from first `]` to end of line